# What is the best practice to save global notifications function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, express

I'm using Node.js to develop my mobile API, and I would like to know where I should store my notifications functions. I called them many times in my code and I don't know if I should use global function, class or anything else.

Here is a example of code I use many times in my routes:

```
const notif = await new Notification({
    read: false,
    type: 'charging',
    content: 'text',
    _user: new ObjectID(id),
    createdAt: Date.now(),
    updatedAt: Date.now()
}).save();

if (notif) {
    const number = await Notification.find({
        _user: new ObjectID(existingUser.id),
        read: false
    }).count();

    const deviceToken = existingUser.device.token;

    const notification = new apn.Notification();

    notification.expiry = keys.apns.expiry;
    notification.badge = number;
    notification.sound = keys.apns.sound;
    notification.alert = 'Message';
    notification.topic = keys.apns.topic;

    apnProvider.send(notification, deviceToken).then(result => {
         console.log(result);
    });

    res.status(200);
    res.send({
        statusCode: 200,
        msg: 'ok'
    });
} else {
    res.status(400);
    res.send({
        statusCode: 400,
        msg: 'error'
    });
}
```

Do I should put all of this code in a class, function, global function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about making this notification reused functionality into a utils module and require it whenever you need it? You could export it using module.exports = {}.

```
// /utils/file
const notification = (arguments) => {/* function details here */}

/* then export as notification  */

module.exports = { notification}
```

Then use it anywhere else as:

```
let {notification} = require('/path/to/utils')
```

You need to isolate what features you use often into this module.
Let me know if this makes any sense or if you need more clarification.

Comment: It seems to be a good idea, but could you explain me how I call it in my case and how I could use it? Do I net to put my `res.status` and `res.json` method in it or not?